# jqgrid z-index issues with chosen select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqgrid, jquery-chosen

I am using a plugin called Chosen Select to create nicer looking dropdowns, but also because it has a search ability inbuilt.

I tried to get it working with a jqgrid generated table but am having issues with z-index'ing, [image: Problem 1]

As shown, the dropdown box gets cut off when over lapping into the next row;
When using the standard inbuilt HTML select this does not happen (the table is in cell edit mode for editing). Is there a way to get this to display over the top of the rows instead? If not, is there a way in jqgrid (or another plugin) where I can have a dropdown list in that cell and have it searchable?

Comment: It looks more like the problem with the parent as the problem with `z-index`. The Chosen should be applied so that the parent of menu (`<ul>`) is `<body>` instead of `<td>` element. You should provide **the demo which reproduce the problem**. It could be important which version of chosen and jqGrid you use (and from which fork of jqGrid; [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7).

Comment: @Oleg , sorry for late reply. I figured out that the problem was to do with overflow settings in my jqgrid css. I am using jqGrid 4.6.0 (didn't know it was so old now). So the drop down can pass over other cells now.

I now face a similar issue with the bottom rows' dropdown not going over the footerbar; This can be fixed with overflow changes however that means when you increase the rows they all appear under the footerbar too.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I ended up using [Select2](https://select2.org/) library, It worked like a charm and I didn't have styles problems with JQgrid